# The below error i am getting when i start the tomcat

Tags: spring-boot

```
    Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
27-Sep-2018 14:42:06.307 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.reportFailure Application run failed
 org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userprofileResource' defined in file [D:\appache\apache-tomcat-8.5.34-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.34\webapps\ng-ols-platformservices\WEB-INF\classes\com\ce\resources\UserprofileResource.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userProfileService': Resolution of declared constructors on bean Class [com.ce.services.UserProfileService] from ClassLoader [ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ng-ols-platformservices
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@c5a425e
] failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:732)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1267)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1124)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:157)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:137)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5245)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:985)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by clearing local maven repository and downloading them again.

linux or mac users can follow below steps.

```
1. navigate to .m2 file
2. execute remove command (rm -rf repository/).
```

Window users :

```
C:\Users\[username]\.m2\repository
```

Comment: I am getting some other exception I edited my question .please look and tell me the solution